# My display stops working

Tags: 20.04, nvidia

I just built a new econo machine.
-Gigabyte x570 aorus elite wifi
-Ryzen 5 5600G
-2x8gb DDR4 3200
-Ubuntu 20.04

The system runs great for a few minutes and then I just lose signal to my display.

I have turned off autodim, automatic suspend. I have not noticed anything like a specific app running or anything, just time passing. It takes about 3 minutes and then "No Signal" and I hafta reboot.

Comment: You could try monitoring GPU info up until the point that you lose connection. I wonder if anything interesting is happening with it.

Comment: Check the logs. The next time it happens, `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` might give you more information. Also, `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e`. to see the logs leading up to the crash.  Also investigate power, fan, dust, ...

Comment: Since I installed a new SSD (I think), mine's been doing the same thing. @ringo what if, when mine "switches off", GPU information goes up to about 20,000%, somehow? I'm opening a new question anyway